# Please Help Me Install Firestorm?

Tags: installation

I have been trying for hours just to install one program. In this time, I've tried my best to follow directions and not screw everything up but I have. I'm new to Linux. I tried to install Firestorm and this is what happened:

```
parent@ubuntu:~$ sudo '/home/parent/Downloads/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.2.1.29803/install.sh' 
[sudo] password for parent: 
Enter the desired installation directory [/opt/firestorm-install]: /home/parent/downloads
 - Installing to /home/parent/downloads
/home/parent/Downloads/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.2.1.29803/install.sh: line 80: /home/parent/downloads/etc/refresh_desktop_app_entry.sh: Permission denied
parent@ubuntu:~$ sudo opt/firestorm-install
sudo: opt/firestorm-install: command not found
parent@ubuntu:~$  ./etc/refresh_desktop_app_entry.sh
bash: ./etc/refresh_desktop_app_entry.sh: No such file or directory
parent@ubuntu:~$ sudo '/home/parent/Downloads/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.2.1.29803/install.sh' 
Enter the desired installation directory [/opt/firestorm-install]: /home/parent
 - Backing up previous installation to /home/parent.backup-2012-08-27
 - Installing to /home/parent
cp: cannot stat `/home/parent/Downloads/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.2.1.29803/*': No such file or directory
Failed
parent@ubuntu:~$
```

Now whenever I go into my files it says it can't find anything. Like `Cannot find home/parent/Downloads`. Now, I KNOW there are downloads. I don't know why it's doing this all of a sudden. I'm so frustrated that I'm ready to just go back to Windows. I've already had to uninstall/reinstall Ubuntu once today. It's looking like I"m going to have to do it again. How can I fix my file problem that I'm now having and can someone please, please tell me how to install Firestorm? I mean they don't even have their repository listed. It's ridiculous to have to go through this over a program. Spotify wasn't hard at all to install so why is this? Someone please help, and I'm sorry if I sound like a total idiot. I'm pretty tech savvy but I'm honestly pretty upset after struggling with this for hours.

*Edit* Okay, I see the problem with the directory files (showing the error I mentioned above when I try to click on them). I can only access my downloads, desktop, ect, through the backup that was created when I tried to install Firestorm. It's like that's the real home now. How can I get it back to the way it was?

*Edit* Ubuntu has stopped working for me on reboot now. It doesn't go past the login screen. This is exactly what happened when I had to uninstall it before after trying to install Firestorm. Maybe I'm giving up too easily but I think I'm just going to go back to Windows. If this is what's going to happen every time I innocently try to install a program then it's just not worth it. I installed it specifically to run Firestorm because Windows sucks up a lot of CPU and causes lag. I still appreciate any input but this is just too much hassle for something that shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Is your processor 64bit? I never had problems with Firestorm viewer until I bought a new laptop which had a i7 processor (64bit) and then by installing ubuntu 12.04 and 13.04 64 bit, the problems started. If so, google for kokua viewer (worked for me for a few days then it stopped without a reason) and singularity 64bit. singularity runs fine on my system.

Comment: You could always try installing Ubuntu in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

I had a go running the same program. It worked fine for me. 

According to the 'README-linux.txt' file:

> The Firestorm Linux client can entirely run from the directory you have
>   unpacked it into - no installation step is required 
> Run ./firestorm from the >installation >directory to start Firestorm.

So in my case, running the program was relatively simple:

Go to the Downloads folder, extract the archive, and then go into the extracted Phoenix folder:

```
cd ~/Downloads/
tar -xvf Phoenix_Firestorm-Release*.tar.bz2
cd ./Phoenix_Firestorm-Release*
```

Provide a script with permission to execute. Executing the script then adds Firestorm to the menu.

```
chmod u+x ./etc/refresh_desktop_app_entry.sh
./etc/refresh_desktop_app_entry.sh
```

After that Firestorm should appear in your menu. It can then be run directly from the extracted archive.

I think your problem with logging in may related to this output:

> parent@ubuntu:~$ sudo '/home/parent/Downloads/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.2.1.29803/install.sh'
>   Enter the desired installation directory [/opt/firestorm-install]: /home/parent
>   - Backing up previous installation to /home/parent.backup-2012-08-27
>   - Installing to /home/parent
>   cp: cannot stat `/home/parent/Downloads/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.2.1.29803/*': No such file or directory
>   Failed

In particular, it seems as if you choose to install the program in the same location as your home directory (due to typing '/home/parent' at the command prompt). Therefore, the installer moved the contents of the home directory to "/home/parent.backup-2012-08-27", which would have lead to some important files being moved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful with what you type into the command line. I can see quite a few typos in your paths.

- You sometimes type `Downloads` and sometimes type `downloads`.
- `opt/firestorm-install` should be `/opt/firestorm-install`, which is why you get the error `sudo: opt/firestorm-install: command not found`
- Finally, `./etc/refresh_desktop_app_entry.sh` looks strange. Should it be `/etc/refresh_desktop_app_entry.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

is you problem solved ?
this is how i found firestorm running on ubuntu 12.04
even if you are running in 64 bit, you need to install 32 bit library

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

hope that works.